# How do I use Twitch API Check User Subscription in Javascript?

Tags: firebase, get, openid-connect, twitch

How do I "Check User Subscription" using Twitch API as explained here:
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-broadcaster-subscriptions

I am using an auth code flow using Firebase OpenID Connect. I can already get the access token. I just don't know how to write the actual API request in JavaScript as explained in the above link.

Can somebody help me with an example of how to write the API GET code in JavaScript?